# jscrollpane stops reinitialising after new content is loaded several times

Tags: javascript, jquery, jscrollpane

i have a weird problem with jscrollpane. I'm coding a horizontal image gallery with scrollbar and mousewheel functionality. The images are loaded via jquery's load() function. But if i load new content several times, jscrollpane stops reinitialising and doesn't display a scrollbar.

Here is my code:

```
$(window).load( function() {
var element = $('.scroll-pane').jScrollPane(
                    {
                        maintainPosition: true, 
                        autoReinitialise: false,
                        animateScroll: true
                    });
var api = element.data('jsp');
    element.bind(
    'mousewheel',
    function (event, delta, deltaX, deltaY)
    {
    api.scrollByX(delta * 360);
    return false;
    }
    ).bind(
        'mouseup',
        function() {
            var pos = api.getContentPositionX();
            var width = api.getContentWidth();
            var foo = pos/200.0;
            var jda = Math.floor(foo);
            var bar = foo-jda;
            var newpos;
            if(bar < 0.5){
                newpos = jda * 200;
            }
            else {
                newpos = (jda+1)*200;
            }
            api.scrollTo(newpos);
    });
$('.loadit').bind(
'click', 
function () {
    var load_content = $(this).attr('link');
    api.getContentPane().empty();
    api.getContentPane().load(
        load_content,
        function() 
        {           
            api.reinitialise();
        });
    return false;
});
```

Am i doing something wrong?